# Is there method to protect coffee from moisture

Tags: kitchen

Yes, tight lid is the best way, you might say, but that is not very easy/creative idea to do it. Have you got your best way to protect coffee from getting wet and damage?

Comment: ground coffee or coffee beans?

Comment: How does your coffee get wet before you use it? What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If its ground coffee, I always keep that in the freezer and use it straight out of the freezer too. I put the original bag inside a ziplok freezer bag and pop it in the bottom drawer of the freezer. Keeps fresher for a lot longer too...

Comment: The condensation created every time you open that frozen bag of coffee will cause more damage than the freezing actually helps. Most experts suggest wrapping the coffee up into smaller portions before freezing so you can remove just enough to use a few days at a time without exposing *all* the coffee every time you open that bag.

Comment: I usually keep it in its container, no humidity issues... @RobertCartaino

Comment: @RobertCartaino - I guess it matters if you drink coffee frequently - I don't, it'll sit in the freezer for easily six months, maybe a year, without being used at all.... and when I do use it, I'll be using half the packet at a time (for 6-8 people)

Comment: Experts I've read recommend *not* freezing coffee -- specifically because of condensation.  if you wrap pre-measured portions before freezing, and let the coffee come up to room temperature before opening, you should avoid most of that and get maximum benefit by freezing your beans or grounds.

Answer (score 1):

Just store your coffee in an airtight container or plastic bag, along with a small pouch of silica gel on top of the contents.

Silica gel is non-toxic, non-flammable, non-reactive and stable with ordinary usage. It absorbs moisture from the surroundings effectively. It is commonly used to dry out empty water bottles and to remove moisture from shoes, which in return prevents the stench.

Comment: Silica gel will continue to absorb moisture below freezing, but effectiveness is somewhat diminished. The optimum performance is at room temperatures between 70-90º F (21-32º C), so you might need to use more of the product to be effective. Silica gel is also "Generally Recognized as Safe" by the FDA, but make sure the packaging used for the gel is *also* safe. The industry standard is  Tyvek or food-grade plastic containers.

Comment: Silica gel granules can be replenished by heating them in an oven or on a heating pan. Secondly, you don't need to freeze the coffee if you are using this technique but rather store it in a cupboard.

Comment: Good point. I was mistakenly associating your idea with a recommendation in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to supply problems importing, roasting, and blending forces me to order and buy a minimum amount of my favourite coffee at a time. It will last me more than a month.

I asked the supplier how best to store my investment.

The supplier suggested I keep/store the unground beans at room temperature in the original corrugated-plastic lined paper bags with a roll-down cuff and metal "closure" seal. Grind as much as you need and roll the cuff to keep air in the package to a minimum for the remainder. If you do refrigerate the beans, let them come to room temperature before grinding to enjoy the full flavour and bouquet from the brew.

I keep unopened bags of coffee in a small carton on the bottom shelf of a cupboard in the kitchen. I've been doing this for years.

I did notice that when I first get the batch of beans from the coffee roasters they're oily and very shiny. As time passes, the gloss slowly disappears and near the end of the batch the beans have a matte finish as the oil gets absorbed into the body of the bean.

Answer (score 0):

Zipper closure plastic bags.  Squeeze out the air when closing, and store them in an opaque canister or similar to keep light out.  This will preserve coffee as well as any other method I've heard of.

Also, buy whole bean coffee and grind it when you're setting up the machine to brew -- whole bean keeps several times longer than ground coffee, and costs no more (you will need to buy a grinder, but they aren't expensive).

Answer (score 0):

We keep our ground coffee in a stainless steel container with a tight lid in the **fridge**.

[image]

The low temperature and dry air in a fridge will not only prevent moisture from entering the ground coffee but it will also help to keep the aroma fresh for a much longer time.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of those airtight jars/containers for sugar,flour,rice,or cracker snacks would work for protecting your coffee from moisture. Searching for those online yields a lot of different brands and styles of containers for you to choose from. An example of what those look like:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use one of these to store my coffee. They are great.
http://www.containerstore.com/s/kitchen/food-storage/canisters/click-clack-pantry-canisters/123d?productId=10033113